Refund.created Webhook and reference to he original transaction
I am in the Authorize.net sandbox.
Upon receiving the refund.created webhook, I need to reference the original transaction that was refunded.
I do see that the webhook payload contains transaction id, but that one refers to the refund transaction itself, not the original transaction.
I.e. the transaction id 80025538888 is not the original transaction.
I am not seeing any other data in the webhook that would allow to find the original transaction.
{
    "notificationId": "cefbb67a-45b8-41c5-8432-b4539c0bd511",
    "eventType": "net.authorize.payment.refund.created",
    "eventDate": "2024-09-16T17:38:06.6496645Z",
    "webhookId": "62e1ce04-9cc3-49fa-8f00-8f7b2e1ca4e0",
    "payload": {
        "responseCode": 1,
        "authCode": "9QU9OQ",
        "avsResponse": "E",
        "authAmount": 91.97,
        "entityName": "transaction",
        "id": "80025538888"
    }
}


Looks like the best way to do that is to use API endpoint getTransactionDetail first with the refund transaction Id, parse out the refTransId from the response.
